# Amazon Web Service Recognition error in POSTMAN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, amazon-rekognition

I am IAM user and trying to hit API **RekognitionService.CreateCOllection** for the testing in POSTMAN, but getting this

```
<InvalidSignatureException>
  <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>
</InvalidSignatureException>
```

My header request is

```
https://rekognition.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/

Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:rekognition.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
Accept-Encoding:identity
X-Amz-Target:RekognitionService.CreateCollections
Content-Length:30
Authorization:AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAJCWZHWIIW7BH5HPA/20180202/us-east-2/rekognition/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=accept-encoding;content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, Signature=847d47d4e323fed46020c9fb2ac32882a01edd6efa179ed241d36d038712469e
X-Amz-Date:20180202T121035Z
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Though it works with same **Access Key Id** and **Secret Key** using **CLI(Command Line Interface)**.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Why do you have `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in the headers, twice?

Answer (score 2):

> First clear all your headers that you have manually added.

Use your `Accesskey`,`SecretKey` and service name as `rekognition` in AWS singature

[image]

Add your `collectionId` in body as raw type.

[image]

After updating your request header look like this

[image]

> Add new header `X-Amz-Target` value as `RekognitionService.CreateCollection` and `Content-Type` as `application/x-amz-json-1.1`